# Nginx: Execute shell script w/ arguments when specific file not found

Tags: nginx, lua

I want to execute a shell script with arguments when a specific file is not found (404).

As a starting point, i used the following snippet:

```
location ~* ^/(?<bz2file>.+\.bz2)$ {
  log_by_lua_block {
    os.execute("/usr/local/bin/script")
  }
}
```

But i don't know, how to run this only, when the file does not exists.

As i read, the `os.execute` doesn't allow arguments as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to open your file as read-only and if the io object is not `nil` and is present, that means your file exists. (But be sure to release the object, otherwise your file will be held by lua until the application is running).

`os.execute` calls the given command in shell, and the function it self does not have any additional arguments. However, you can pass the command-line arguments in the single string which you are executing the command and it will work perfectly fine, just like executing a command using a terminal app. An example for running os.execute with arguments is:

```lua
os.execute("echo hello world")
os.execute("command arg1 arg2 arg3")
```

To achieve your goal in pure Lua, without any additional libraries you can use the code below:

```lua
local f = io.open("/usr/local/bin/script", "r") -- Open our file read-only.
-- Is the IO object valid?
if f ~= nil then
    -- In case it exists, our file is valid, so we need to release it before we can execute it.
    io.close(f)

    -- Execute using our arguments.
    os.execute("/usr/local/bin/script arg1 arg2 arg3")
end
```